# How do you turn off caching of credentials in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I recently built a web app in MVC4 that uses CAC authentication. Everything is working fine except that my app doesn't always going to the login action result everytime. I realized that the reason is because IIS is caching my credentials the first time which I don't want it to do. How do I keep IIS from caching my login credentials but keep my images, css, javascript cached?

Comment: Try from a different browser - are the credentials gone? IIS isn't caching your credentials - if you are using Forms auth, a cookie is being saved and your session is being found when you visit the side.  If you make it so that the cookie is removed when you close your browser, that'll do the trick.

Comment: Followup: This old article (yes, the examples are in VB) does a nice job of explaining the process: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb

Comment: Tagging on to @mattw - the cookie is removed when the server is rebooted or the service is cycled as well.

Comment: @TechieJoe Yes and No. The cookie remains (it is stored on the user's machine), but the session that the cookie refers to is gone/cleared.  Big gotcha here: if you are storing session in a database or somewhere other than in ASP.NET [which you have to do if you are load balancing your app] the session will stick around.  Recycling the AppPool won't clear the session in that case.

Comment: @TechieJoe - that is incorrect.  the cookie is stored on the client. What you may be referring to is that if the machineKey is set to autogenerate, an IIS/server reboot may cause a new machineKey to be generated, thus invalidating existing authentication cookies...or what MattW said as well :)

Comment: Ahhh my bad.  I misunderstood the role of the cookie and the services when cycled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS should not be caching your credentials, the login cookie just has not expired when you close and reopen the website.  I am trying to locate information regarding Common Access Card authentication, but I am assuming it is very much like Forms Authentication.

When someone logs into your website, your website issues an encrypted cookie.  This cookie is sent with each request to your site in order to authorize the user for your actions.

In your web.config, there is a section to handle how long this cookie is valid as well as items such as your login url.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/User/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

The timeout attribute is the time, in minutes, that the cookie will remain valid.  So, in the same browser, as long as the cookie has not expired, the user will not have to login again.  The default timeout is 20 minutes I believe and has a "sliding expiration", which means as long as the user is doing stuff on your site, the cookie's expiration time will continue to slide out, keeping your site from kicking an active user back to the login page in the middle of using your application.

Comment: You were right. I just had to remove the expiration date of my cookie.